# I want that await method will return or update the value first then go to next line in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to upload image and i need first that image upload to storage and then donwload url set to imageUrl String url. So that i can pass it into api call. But by using await method its skipped that line of code and moves ahead. And URL is updating after api call.

I have attached the code image for best understanding.
[image: Await Method]

Comment: what do you mean by "But by using await method its skipped that line of code and moves ahead"? do you mean that `imageUrl` is not set or what?

Comment: Yes imageUrl not set at first its skipping that line bcz of await

Comment: `putFile` is also async, so you should `await` that as well.

Comment: Still skipping code, Is there any method that i can use instead of await?

Comment: `imageUrl = imageUrl` looks nonsensical.

Comment: Its ok leave that line I just need that this line when completed and get data then we jump to next line. I need synchronous process 1 by 1 line.

imageUrl = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

Comment: and what value does it have after `imageUrl =
await ....` statement? tried to add `print('imageUrl: $imageUrl');`? what do you see on the logs?

Comment: The `await`ed line will *not* be skipped; that's the entire point of using `await`!  If you're observing that lines are being skipped, then: A) You're not using `await` everywhere you should. Enable the [`unawaited_futures` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html). B) You're not observing what you think are.  Are you *sure* you're seeing `setState` called before your `Future`s complete?  Are you *sure* that you're not seeing `setState` triggered from something else, perhaps from a different invocation of `uploadProfileImage`?

Comment: On first its having a last imageUrl and after completing await method it has firebase storage image downloadUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by making onTap() method async and await uploadprofile() method call. Its working good now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
.then((value) => setState(() {
  isModifyPhoto = true;
  imageUrl = value;
}));
```